# is "LIKE" query optimized for search bar use for huge database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a search bar in my header and it will search through a large database of businesses and check 4 columns of that table for similar words as the user searchs for.

my code is as below using "LIKE" for querying through them.
because databse would be very large as the projects grows, like 100000+ businesses, I was wondering if it is optimized or not? should i consider something else for searching through the database for similar words?

```
$result = Business::where('name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
  ->orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
  ->orWhere('website','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
  ->orWhere('facebook','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
  ->orWhere('twitter','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
  ->get();
```

Comment: you can concat the for cols and search with like in the concat string

Comment: @MustafaGoda didn't get what you meant, can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: i mean you can use mongodb and search in all table using concat for columns you need to search

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend you to use straight SQL quires to achieve you search of very large database. Firstly it would be a very heavy process on DB, due to which response time can increase.

You would be better of achieving this by using something like [Elastisearch](https://www.elastic.co/). You will need to do additional things when you insert or update records but in the long run when you query on that data you will get a better performance.

Note: You will need additional server or services which may increase your running cost. But it will reduce the load on the database.

Comment: that would be extra work and cost at the start of our projects which we are not prepared to afford at the moment

Comment: Ok but for the data load you are expecting going with a direct sql query would result in long wait period. You can try creating table views to ease in some load. Still you are bound to have delays due to the large data. Additional effort to maximise productivity is viable i guess.

Comment: better performance comes with some cost, but i think Elastisearch will help you if you learn it.

Comment: Other options, you could learn about indexing on MYSQL. Both are extra work.